# Dynamically add an icon with JS

Tags: javascript, image

I have a responsive tabbed section on a page (that changes to an accordion for mobile view) that is controlled with JS. The tabs are dynamically created with the script which all works great. The problem I have now is I need to add an icon under each heading. Is there a way to also call in an icon image as well as the text for the heading if I name the files icon-1, icon-2, icon-3 etc. to coincide with the list items being created?

This is the section on script creating the tab list heading:

```js
var $tabListItem = $('<li/>', { 
  'class': 'responsive-tabs__list__item',
  id: 'tablist' + tablistcount + '-tab' + tabcount,
  'aria-controls': 'tablist' + tablistcount +'-panel' + tabcount,
  'role': 'tab',
  tabindex: 0,
  text: $tabHeading.text(),
  keydown: function (objEvent) {
  
  if (objEvent.keyCode === 13) { // if user presses 'enter'
   $tabListItem.click();
  }
},
```

I can add the entire script and page code if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't run. Please include a complete piece of code so we can help more. With regards to your question - can you define the icons in CSS?

Comment: Just worked out how to do it with CSS - thanks